# Jmeter - how to add delay between requests in concurrency thread group

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I have a load test case, where the user first requests an access token and then sends second request to a REST API endpoint. The number of users increases by 10 every 5 seconds, ie. 10 requests at test start, after 5 seconds 20 requests, after another 5 seconds 30 requests, etc. However I would like to send requests only once every 5 seconds, when the number of users increases. Is there a way to achieve this in Jmeter?

I decided to choose concurrency thread group and flow control action for my solution, but it doesn't feel accurate enough, when I check the report dashboard, the number of token requests and API calls do not match, although they should. Is there a better way to do this?

1. Here's my concurrency thread group setup
   [image]
2. Thread group setup, in the flow control action sampler I set pause to 5000 ms

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **really** want to send 1 request each 5 seconds you can consider using  [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) configured like:

[image]

However I fail to see why would you need 120 users in that case, 1 user will be more than sufficient.

More information: [Using JMeter’s Throughput Shaping Timer Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-shaping-timer-plugin)

Comment: Maybe I didn't worded my question the best, my apologies. What I am trying to simulate is increasing number of users every 5 seconds, with each user sending access token request and API request every 5 seconds. I.e. when I start the test, there should be 5 active threads sending 1 request each (5 in total), after 5 seconds Jmeter should create 5 more threads and send 10 requests in total, etc.

Comment: The solution would be the same, just amend the "RPS" accordingly